# Share HTML form data between two different webpages

Tags: javascript, html

I want two webpages in my website in such a way that:

1. Users can input their data into some textfill/textarea (html form) in webpage-1.
2. Their data is shown in webpage-2.

```
**webpage-1:(user page)**

post :
name:....
age:....
roll:...
description:......


**webpage-2:(admin page)**

post no:1
name:....
age:....
roll:...
description:..........

post no:2 
name:....
age:....
roll:...
description:..........

post no:3 
name:...
age:....
roll:...
description:..........
```

Comment: You can do this Javascript localStorage for save and use data on one website having multiple webpages without backend or Database.

Comment: Are both webpages called on the same client? Or different clients? What have you tried?

Comment: same clients  @bloodyKnuckles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic architecture of your website should be something like this. Design both pages and share the data using local storage.

Follow these steps:

1. Design your User page. Add a form to using which the user can input data related to the post. Use `setItem()` method of localStorage web api to store posts in an array.

```
var posts = [];

localStorage.setItem("posts", JSON.stringify(posts));
```

2. Design the admin panel where you have to show the data. Fetch the posts array from local storage using `getItem()` method.

```
var storedPosts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("posts"));
```

The data is stored in browser's permanent memory. This way you won't lose your posts data while moving from User page to Admin page.

Read this [article](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/how-to-use-localstorage-with-javascript/) for a detailed explanation of localStorage along with examples and projects.